# Library or API for Creating Progress Bar Needed

Tags: php, jquery, web-applications, progress-bar

Fist all...i am not sure PROGRESS BAR is the appropriate word to describe what i actually want..but for lack of a more apt word, i am stuck with it :(

This is what i need.

I am working on an Application in which users of the application, depending on how they interact with the application, and the level of activity they get to earn points.

The thing now is i want to represent the points earned in a graphical way. I need a graphical indicator...like a horizontal slider that indicates the points earned by each user of the Application on their profile page.

I am using PHP...and i am comfortable with jQuery on the front end.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Your response would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar

You can pass the value needed for display as a hidden input and get the value when generating the progressbar.